# Get currently selected value in editable select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used editable select Jquery plugin ,now the problem is i want the currently selected value of editable select control with out on change or other event

link to [Editable select](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Custom-Filterable-Select-Box-Editable-Select)

I have tried following till now but no success

```
$('#customer_name').find('li.selected').value()
$('#customer_name').siblings('.es-list').find('li.selected').value()
$("#customer_name").val();
```

HTML

```
<select id="customer_name" name="customer_name" class="form-control"> 
<?php
    foreach($customers as $customer){
     echo "<option value='".$customer['cust_id']."'>".$customer['cust_name']." </option>";
    }//foreach
?>
</select> 


$('#customer_name').editableSelect();
```

Comment: actually $(selector).val() is working here, recheck the ID

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed I am getting the text instead of value

Comment: show the HTML please

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed i have updated the code

Comment: where in the code did you place the plugin script?

Answer (score 1):

I have dome some R&D regarding this question and I have found something which helps me to achieve the goal. So, I am sharing the **Jquery code** with the **Link** so that you can get more information.

**Jquery code for getting the selected value:**

```
        $('#onselect')
            .editableSelect()
            .on('select.editable-select', function (e, li) {
                console.log('Seletced Value: ');
                console.log(li.val() + '. ' + li.text());
        });
```

**Ref. Website** [Jquery Editable Select Example](https://indrimuska.github.io/jquery-editable-select/)

Thanks.

Comment: i have this solution but as i have mentioned in question **i want the currently selected value of editable select control with out on change or other event**

Comment: @vikas-chauhan Okay. It's my mistake to take in a different way. Although you want the selected value without any event. So, I have tried to get the value without any event trigger. I got the value by using **jquery code**. My code is **$('#onselect').val();**. Please try this to get the selected value. If this is not working then please let me know. I'll try other ways. Thanks

Comment: $('#onselect').val(); this will return selected drop down text as i said i want the value of selected option value.

Comment: In my given example, you can find selected drop-down text as well as value both. But if you still are not getting your target value, can you please elaborate more so that I can give you exact solution.

Comment: your solution works only if change event occurs and what i want is  currently selected value of editable select control **with out on change or other event**

Comment: Okay, Vikas. Give me some time I will try to resolve your query asap. And in the mean time, if you will find any solution, please update here. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Vikar, 
try to use this syntax maybe ur problem will be solved.
$('.es-list').find('.es-visible').attr('value');
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const x = $('#customer_name').attr('value')
```

this should work.

if this doesn't work, then your HTML element doesn't have an attribute called value, try adding a value & id to any HTML element then do $(id).attr('value') and you'll get the value attribute

Comment: actually this should work, can you show me the output? open the console after the page renders & write the code I mentioned and see if it works

Comment: I tested and it's working, just be sure to use x for whatever reason you wanna use it, because the code I mentioned is just assigning a value o x

Comment: can you please provide me jsfiddle ?

Comment: Open the link you provided in the main question, Right click on the textbox after 'into this', right click on it from the console, add attribute, add a value attribute say value='30', now open the console menu from above, select your element & say .attr('value') it should work I tried

Comment: I have followed this step but still i dint get value
what i have done is
1. added the value to currently selected item
2. added id to textbox **testing**
3. checked with following code $('#testing').attr('value')

Answer (score 0):

I have read the docs but i could't find any solution so what i have done is stored the value of editable select in hidden filed for the first time and when user change the value then i have jquery to update the value .
if any one has solution please mention